# It is possible to know if a string is encoded in base64?

Tags: ios, swift, base64, qr-code

Simple as that.

I'm making an app where the user has to scan a QR code (which basically is a base64 encoded string), is there any way to verify that the string is encoded in base64 before decode and follow the flow of the application?

My code would be responsible for that is:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRectZero
        return
    }

    let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

    if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
        let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
        qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds

        if metadataObj.stringValue != nil /* Verify that string is base 64 before continue */ {
            let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: metadataObj.stringValue, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
            let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println(decodedString)
        }

        /* More code */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need to check *in advance* if the string contains valid 
Base-64. You just have to check the return value, which is `nil` when the input is not recognized as valid Base-64:

```
if let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: someString, options: nil) {
    // ...
} else {
    println("Not Base64")
}
```

Update for **Swift 4:**

```
if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: someString) {
    // ...
} else {
    print("Not Base64")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression to check a string match base64 encoding or not, like this:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)$
```

In base64 encoding, the character set is [A-Z,a-z,0-9,and + /], if rest length is less than 4, fill of `'='` character.

`^([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*` means the String start with 0 time or more base64 group.

`([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==)` means the String must end of 3 forms in `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{4}` or `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=` or `[A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==`

Basic Rule is:

- Check that the length is a multiple of 4 characters
- Check that every character is in the set A-Z, a-z, 0-9, +, / except
  for padding at the end which is 0, 1 or 2 '=' characters

Answer (score 0):

Please Use [For Base64 Validation](https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator)

OtherWise Add The Pod in The Project `pod 'SwiftValidators'`

Example

```
if Validators.isBase64()("mnbzcxmnbnzzxmnb==")
{
print("Validate Yes")
}
else
{
print("Not Validate")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string extension to validate this and make use of `guard`or a simple if would also do

```
  extension String
  {
    func isStringBase64() -> Bool {
        guard Data(base64Encoded: self) != nil else {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply doesn't work. In my case I've a string that I know is encoded in base 64 when I try to check with this it return true. When I try with a string not encode in base 64 it return true anyway... Useless...

Comment: @lucgian841 Can you provide me the string which you try, as when i try with a simple string like "Hello World" it returns false which means the string is not base64, and as you can see I am not doing anything special here but using apple's own class to verify. Curious to know with what string you tried it with?