# NSData baseEncodedString returning nil

Tags: swift, nsdata

What am I doing wrong in my swift project? My line

```
NSData.init(base64EncodedString: parameters[0], options: .IgnoreUnknownCharacters)
```

is returning nil.

```
parameters[0] = "LFGNzD83/G8"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like that's a valid b64 string. Try this web app to encode some text https://www.base64decode.org/. For example, `VGVzdGluZw==` is the word testing.

```
let b64String = "VGVzdGluZw==" // Is "Testing" b64 encoded from utf8
let encodedData = NSData.init(base64EncodedString: b64String, options: [])
print(String(data: encodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)) // > "Testing"
```

Noted in another SO answer, "padding at the end which is 0, 1 or 2 '=' characters" [It is possible to know if a string is encoded in base64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28825485/it-is-possible-to-know-if-a-string-is-encoded-in-base64)

So it looks like a quick check of equal signs at the end is enough to tell you it's not base64.

Comment: I don't think it is; however, add an equal sign at the end and it decodes. You have eleven characters there, b64 is in pairs and is padded with equal signs to make that true https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64